# No response after initial meetings for a Postdoc position

Tags: postdocs

I have applied for an open postdoc position in one of the labs (outside my country).

After a fast and positive initial response, I had a casual/ unofficial meeting with few lab members and the discussion was fruitful (according to me). They have suggested that I speak with few other team members and shared their contact details.

However, the person whom I'm supposed to meet or discuss my prospects with has not responded to my mails in over three weeks. I'm confused at this point. This delay doesn't seem positive to me.

Do I have a fair chance with this position ?

Should I write back to them or wait to get a response from them?

What is the ideal timeline for the final interview of the potential candidate by the PI of the lab?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/141880/no-response-to-after-phd-interview-germany, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/166474/no-response-after-phd-interview-with-good-feedback-follow-up-emails, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/167298/does-being-ghosted-mean-rejection-after-phd-interview, https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/126034/no-response-after-phd-interview

Comment: Sadly, being "ghosted" is not at all unusual. After an interview is a little less usual, but still. And timelines are often set by "individual factors" behind the scenes (e.g., waiting for a grant to come in). See the linked posts.